# How to avoid subfolder creation when using git svn?

Tags: git, svn, git-svn

I am trying to clone the [achartengine subversion repository](https://code.google.com/p/achartengine/source/checkout) running the following command:

```
git svn clone http://achartengine.googlecode.com/svn -s achartengine
```

However, after process finished a unneeded subfolder is created:

```
├── achartengine
│   └── achartengine
│       ├── AndroidManifest.xml
│       ├── assets
│       ├── bin
│       ├── build.xml
│       ├── demo
│       ├── extra
│       ├── lib
│       ├── lint.xml
│       ├── pom.xml
│       ├── project.properties
│       ├── res
│       ├── src
│       └── test
└── .git
```

Is there a way to avoid the subfolder creation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO git-svn does the right thing, there is an unneeded subfoler in svn repo's trunk view.  If you really want to avoid a subfoler, remove it in svn first.

Another way to solve this problem is to clone the subdirectory directly:

```
git svn clone http://achartengine.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/achartengine achartengine
```

Comment: I thought I tried this before. Obviously not. Thank you. - Interesting enough: the [GitHub importer](https://porter.github.com/new) does still create a subfolder.